# How to compare file names which is in format of timestamp and retrieve the file which has latest date?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am very new to shell scripting, I have a scenario where i have many of files which is inside a folder and which has a naming convention such as (`test-2020-11-19-1652.tgz` - yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm), i need to compare the date(need to get from file name) and pick the latest one and need to unzip them and need to rename that particular file. i tried in many ways but end-up with an error due to beginner level.can anyone help me with this?

**Expectation**
In this above case i need to pick file `shop_db-2020-11-19-1652.tgz` because it is the latest file in the folder.and need to unzip it and rename it it `shop_db`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a file pattern always returns a sorted list. So it makes it possible to extract the ultimate entry you want with:

Using POSIX shell syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

last() {
  shift $(($# - 1))
  printf %s "$1"
}

lastfile=$(last shop_db*.tgz)

if [ "$lastfile" = 'shop_db*.tgz' ]; then
  lastfile=
fi
```

- `shift $(($# - 1))`: Shift all arguments away except the last one.
- `printf %s "$1"`: Print the last argument since there is only one left.

Using Bash syntax:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

lastfile=$(printf '%s\0' shop_db*.tgz | tail -z -n1 | tr -d \\0)
```

- `shopt -s nullglob`: A Bash feature to return an empty list if no file matches the pattern.
- `printf '%s\0' shop_db*.tgz`: Print a `null` delimited list of files matching the `shop_db*.tgz` globbing pattern.
- `| tail -z -n1`: Extract the last record from this `null` delimited list.

Alternate method using only Bash built-in:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

while read -r -d '' f && [ "$f" ]
do
  lastfile=$f
done < <(
  printf '%s\0' shop_db*.tgz
)

echo "$lastfile"
```

And finally expanding the globbing pattern into an array, and extracting the last index:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

array=(shop_db*.tgz)
if [ ${#array[@]} -gt 0 ]
then
  lastfile=${array[-1]}
fi

echo "$lastfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you require can actually be achieved by utilising awk with find:

```
find . -name "shop_db*.tgz" | awk 'END { "tar -xvf "$0|getline fil;system("mv "fil" shop_db") }'
```

Look for files starting with shop_db and ending with .tgz. Pipe the output into awk and un tar the file in verbose mode, reading the uncompressed file name into the variable fil using awk's getline. Utilise this fil variable to run the necessary move command to rename the file to shop_db using awk's system function. As the output from find will already be ordered, we utilise the END block within awk to process the last compressed file piped from find.

Comment: Or a one-liner POSIX grammar shell built-ins, no sub-processes, no awk interpreter: `set -- shop_db*.tgz; shift $(($# - 1)); echo "$1"`